# Lines sometimes disappear when editing Postgis layer in QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a GIS tech editing a watercourse layer that is located in a Postgres/PostGIS table. She is using QGIS 2.16 on Windows 7 and I am running PG 9.5. All editing, which includes modifying existing watercourses and adding new one, saves fine in the DB. There are no permission issues, no errors, no problems whatsoever.

However, every now and then she adds a new line, presses save, turns off the editing session, and the line disappears. I checked the PG logs and the QGIS error console and no errors (relating to this issue). The only repeated PG log error relates to permission issues relating to the topology schema – which is probably another issue altogether. Bottom line: at the time of these events, there are no logged errors or QGIS errors.

Does anyone know how to prevent such data loss when creating new rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're giving the new feature an attribute in the field that QGIS is using to visualize the data - for example - if you add a new feature and QGIS is using the 'TYPE' column to render the lines, and you don't put a value in the TYPE field, the feature will disappear! That new line, however, is in the database...

Comment: Bingo! I took a look at how the rule-based styling was set up, and for some reason some new lines were not being styled -- hence, they vanished upon save.

Comment: @Cliff good stuff!